# PHPBB integrated login returning multiple cookies of the same name

Tags: php, session, cookies, phpbb3

I have a website with a PHPBB 3 forum. The website's authentication mechanism is based on PHPBB. I have migrated the site to a new dedicated server where I created an ubuntu VM on HyperV. When I try logging in to the new site, multiple cookies of the same name are set. These are the auto login (k), user (u) and session ID (sid) cookies. Only 1 set of these cookies tell us that the user was authenticated. I have attached two screenshots of the response headers (one from the old host & one from the new one).

Is there a PHP setting I can toggle to prevent this? The PHP files and database are identical between the two hosts. I tried fiddling with the PHP cookie name setting in the config table, clearing caches & session tables. But nothing seems to help.

Strangely though, if I manually add the sid as query string to the web page, I am shown as being logged in.

### New Site

[image: New Site]

### Old Site

[image: Old Site]

Comment: Did you integrate through an API or did you hack into PHPBB3?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I am using this - [link](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4826-PHP-Manipulate-accounts-of-PHPBB-3-users.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the cookie path is set right... Are you, or a select few, the only ones with this problem? IF so, I would first try to clear all those cookies from the browser and start over. I've solved many a cookie problem with phpBB like that. A second option is to go into the admin panel and change the cookie name. That will invalidate all login cookies and kick everyone off the board... but they should be able to log in afterward.